# Need a way to access the public members of an anonymous Java class (or some good alternative)

Tags: java

I am creating a number of constants, each with some number of uniquely named public constant fields.  This is what I'm trying to do, but it does not compile due to the fact that T1 in the example below is an anonymous class.

```
public class Templates {

    public static class Template {}

    public static final Template T1 = new Template(){

        public final String NAME = "My Name";
    };

    public static final Template T2 = new Template(){

        public final String THING1 = "This is a thing.";
        public final String THING2 = "This is another thing.";
    };

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(T1.NAME); // does not compile
    }
}
```

I am seeking either some way to make the above work or some good alternative approach.  Each template will have a different number of constants with different names.  Any help is appreciated!

---

So far, the best alternative I have found is to use a Singleton design pattern, but if anyone knows of a less code-intensive approach, I would love to know about it.

Comment: Just use an enum instead?

Comment: +1 @NimChimpsky.  This _isn't doable_ with anonymous classes like you're trying to do.

Comment: There are two reasons that I'd rather not use an enum.  Firstly, these objects may need to have methods in addition to constants.  Secondly, and more importantly, I want to keep the elements organized.  So rather than have T1_NAME, T2_THING1, T2_THING2, I want the organize the constants into logical groups.

Comment: @sgware, you can do all that with enums.

Comment: @svz Neat!  If I can add arbitrary methods and fields to enums, then enums should be just what I need.  If you post an answer, I will mark it as best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [this](http://boyns.blogspot.ru/2008/03/java-15-explained-enum.html) blogpost, enums are simple static final classes. The only difference is that instead of having to write:

```
public class Direction extends java.lang.Enum{
    public final static Direction NORTH;
    ...

    static{
        NORTH = new Direction("NORTH", 0);
        ...

        VALUES = new Direction[(size here)];
        VALUES[0] = NORTH;
        ...
    }
} // taken from the referred blogpost
```

you just write a single line of code: `enum Direction{}` and get all the stuff above.

What this means is that you can handle enums the way you handle classes.

**You can add arbitrary methods to your enums:**

```
public enum TestEnums {
    TEST_ENUM_1;

    void doSomething(){
         System.out.print("I'm a method in enum");
    }
}
TestEnums.TEST_ENUM_1.doSomething(); //to call the method
```

**You can add fields to enums:**

```
public enum TestEnums {
    TEST_ENUM_1;

    String message = "I'm a field in enum";

    void doSomething(){
         System.out.print(message);
    }
}
```

**You can use constructors in enums:**

```
public enum TestEnums {
    TEST_ENUM_1("I'm a field in enum 1"),
    TEST_ENUM_2("I'm a field in enum 2");

    String message;

    TestEnums(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    void doSomething(){
         System.out.print(message);
    }
}
```

**You can make enums implement interfaces:**

```
public enum TestEnums implements IEnum{
    TEST_ENUM_1("I'm a field in enum 1");

    String message;

    TestEnums(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
         System.out.print(message);
    }
}

interface IEnum{
    void doSomething();
}
```

But remember that you **can't extend** enums as they are final.

With all this you can implement the behavior you want with groups, fields and methods, getting singletons and compiler checks for free. Using interfaces for enums will also allow you to extend painlessly the number of operations your enums provide or use different classes instead.

Comment: I am torn between this answer and @C.Champagne's answer.  This answer is more complete and achieves what I want to do, but if I or anyone else ever needed to add more templates, they would need to use Champagne's solution.  Wish I could make both as best answer.

Comment: @sgware, enums can also hold inner enums if you need that for some reason :)

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure why you want to do that,
but annonymous class is a differnt class that extends the Class that declares with new keyword.

like

```
Template T1 = new Template(){

    public final String NAME = "My Name";
};
```

the new class that is created is not Template but a class that extends Template. that extended class has Name variable not in Template class

and T1 can only see its variable or its parent variable but doesnt not or cannot have information about its child.

Comment: Right; I know why what I'm doing does not work.  I'm trying to find a way around it or a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

if you have to use annonymous class than you need to declare the variables in Template as well and initialize them from anonymous class, its ugly but possible :-

```
class Templates {

public static class Template {

    public String Name;
    public String THING1;
    public String THING2;
}


public static final Template T1 = new Template() {

    {
        Name = "My Name";
    }
};

public static final Template T2 = new Template() {
    {
        THING1 = "This is a thing.";
        THING2 = "This is another thing.";
    }


};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(T1.Name); // compiles now
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the closest thing to what you intend to do is to tu define inner classes or -better interfaces. If you define classes, you need to set your class members as static.

```
public class Templates {


    public static interface T1 {

        public final static String NAME = "My Name";
    };

    public static interface T2{

        public final String THING1 = "This is a thing.";
        public final String THING2 = "This is another thing.";
    };

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(T1.NAME); // DOES compile
    }
}
```

BTW, instead of using Strings constants, you could also replace them by an enum.

Comment: This is the best answer I have seen so far.  I think I would need to use classes, because I will also need to define methods with a body.

Comment: @sgware Indeed. I had forgot this point but as I wrote in my answer, you can use a `class` instead of an `interface`. You just need to set your constant as `final static`.